# Graph permissions not making any sense

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph Explorer to test out some basic user profile queries that I want to perform.

I authenticated with Graph Explorer with just the initial default permission scopes `openid profile User.Read email` and tested the `/me` endpoint which was successful.

Then I use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userEmail}/?$select=id,interests,pastProjects,skills`, where `{userEmail}` is a different user in my organisation. I get a valid response, listing all of the profile information from the `interests,pastProjects,skills` fields. Having just `User.Read`, I don't believe that I should be able to see the extended profile of other users, yet it works fine (I get a valid 200 response with a JSON body and the field values completed, as below).

[Valid response for another user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCfVT.png)

From the MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-32 it says that `User.Read.All` or `User.ReadBasic.All` is required to read other user's profiles / basic profiles respectively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-40 shows that the `User.Read` delegated permission (which I verified in AAD is the permission I have, rather than the Application Permission) should only allow:

> *User.Read*: Read the full profile for the signed-in user (`GET /me`).

To further my confusion, this whole investigation was because my application uses the delegated permission `User.ReadBasic.All`, and can *still* view the extended properties, even though this permission is supposed to only allow the following fields:

- displayName
- givenName
- id
- mail
- photo
- securityIdentifier
- surname
- userPrincipalName

Using the same application, a client (in their AAD tenant) gets an error response from the API:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

Which ironically is what I'd expect since I'm not requesting the Admin permission `User.Read.All`.
Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Graph API will sometimes return an empty list for extended properties if the user has insufficient permissions to read those properties.

To be sure that there is a permissions issue find a user that has an entry in the specific field. e.g., interest: ["Golfing"]. Then see if you can read the property with actual entries.

You can test with identities as shown in the below screenshots.[image]

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more specific (I've edited my post to be more clear). I not only get back a valid 200 response, but it contains the field values. This is still just with the permissions `openid profile User.Read email`